# Как изменить основную(default) ветку в gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Погуглив этот вопрос нашел много уже не актуальных ответов, так как, судя по всему, интерфейс gitlab меняется со временем.

Comment: какая версия gitlab у вас?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В gitlab версий 12.8 - 14.4 это делается в меню **Settings -> Repository**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]